# react-bootstrap-datetimerangepicker: no text input field

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I am attempting to use react-bootstrap-datetimerangepicker, and in the online demo (http://luqin.xyz/react-bootstrap-datetimerangepicker/#/) there appears to be a text input field at the top of the menu that opens on click.

In my implementation, that text input box does not appear.

I was wondering if I am importing the .css incorrectly? But I copied the source code for the example and I still get this result.

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import DatetimeRangePicker from 'react-bootstrap-datetimerangepicker';
import 'bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css';

class Sidebar extends Component{
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fromDate: new Date(),
      toDate: new Date(),
    };
 }
 handleApply(event, picker) {
    this.setState({
      fromDate: picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
      toDate: picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
    });
 }
 render(){
    return(
         <DatetimeRangePicker
              timePicker={true}
              timePicker24Hour={true}
              timePickerSeconds={true}
              showDropdowns={true}
              onApply={this.handleApply}
              opens={"center"}
              startDate={this.state.fromDate}
              endDate={this.state.toDate}>

               <Button >
                Date and Time Range
               </Button>}

         </DatetimeRangePicker>
  )
}
}
```

Comment: Im positive that this has something to do with the version of react daterangepicker that im using, I'm switching the versions and nothing is changing yet though

Answer (score 1):

So as I speculated, this has to do with the version I was using.

As explained here:
https://github.com/skratchdot/react-bootstrap-daterangepicker/issues/185

I switched my version by running npm i --save bootstrap-daterangepicker@2.1.27 and now its back to the old version with the manual text input pickers